# Spawning Sprite problems in swift3 xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, loops

Im having some issues, I have sprites spawn on the right of the screen and work there way left then when they go off the screen they are removed from the scene and the process restarts. I want every spawn to get quicker by like 0.1seconds.

Problem is i am calling my spawn function when the game starts and its on a constant loop so i cant then update the delay.

Spawn Code:

```
    func spawnBirdRL() {                                                    
    let spawn = SKAction.run({ () -> Void in
        self.createEnemyBird()
    })
    let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: (TimeInterval(spawnDuration)))
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])


    self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(sequence), withKey: "Spawn")
}
```

Which is being called in the `TouchesBegan` function.

It creates the enemy bird and runs the movement loop over and over

Comment: You should run a new delayed `SKAction` each time one has ended.

Comment: Could you expand on that? Maybe print some code out as to how this would be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the question slightly with more information...